# How to hedge an ETF position with a basket of its underlying components

Tags: optimization, hedging, etf

In practice, when one takes on a large equity ETF position, I would imagine it's not necessarily "optimal" to hedge using a basket of all the constituents even though that should be a perfect hedge. What's the common approach to picking an optimal hedge basket given constraints on its size?

Comment: In statistics, I would run PCA analysis to determine constituents that define 90%, 95% or any desired level volatility of the underlying.

Comment: That seems reasonable - I feel naive approach of truncating off smallest constituents wouldn't be optimal but not 100% on why.

Comment: My strong feeling, approximating ETF returns with a pruned basket of underlyings is a statistical exercise. And the commonly accepted approach to this problem in statistics is PCA, as i said. In fact, I saw this suggestion in some "python for finance" books, do not remember the name. As to pruning constituents with smallest weights.... what if a company with 1% weight has unusually high volatility thus impacting returns of the total ETF???

Comment: That makes sense. It's the best approximation with less dimensions where metric is return difference. Doesn't seem like you can get away with something simple to run "real-time"

Comment: to clarify a bit on my earlier hasty statement #1 : PCA will return new "factors" (PC1, PC2, PC3 ... PCN, where N is the number of constituents in ETF) with their contribution to return volatility, NOT constituents volatility. So, you would need to look at the loadings of the several PC's that deliver desired level of approximation.

Comment: Here's an interesting fact:  not even the ETF _administrators_ necessarily have the "right" portfolio.  This is particularly common for corporate bond ETFs.  Due to liquidity concerns its just too hard to have the same mix of bonds from the tracked index, so they publish a list of more-or-less equivalent bonds they will accept as components substitutes in creation/redemption trades.

Comment: @bushmanov: not sure I understand. So you take, say, the 1st principal component. It will give you weights for ALL the basket component. Then what? How do you pick a smaller basket?

Comment: @LazyCat you're absolutely right, see my last correction above. From there, I would start accumulating PC's until they capture enough volatility and see IF the resulting basket contains fewer constituents. That was my conjecture, not the answer BTW....

Comment: Yeah, I just don't see how it can work: the first component will have a non zero weight for every basket stock, and these weights will never cancel out...

Comment: @LazyCat it's a bit more complicated than that: components may have zero weights, weights could cancel out..... (hint: they are orthogonal). If i had a data on an ETF, I would try PCA first. Maybe some other ideas, like close constituents appearing in the same PC. It's worth trying.....

Comment: I could try to explain why they shouldn't cancel (hint: components are orthogonal), but I just know from experience they don't.